# Import XML in QGIS

Tags: qgis, xml

I have an XML file that contains the following text, that I want to import in QGIS:

```
<bgeom>AAAAAAMAAAABAAAABkEVkXO2K2roQVDSURW3F1lBFZG96URnOEFQ0lA6MfihQRWRv0/FBIFBUNJQoTw2EUEVkgXfBvaUQVDSaYPLkjpBFZHBjTWoWEFQ0mpR4A0bQRWRc7YrauhBUNJRFbcXWQ==</bgeom>
```

Definitely is a geometry feature (polygon - cultivation area). Is anybody familiar with that kind of content?

Comment: Looks like a Base64-encoded binary stream to me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Any idea how can I check this out. I am not familiar whith all these.